# How do I use my Logitech G9x mouse on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, mouse, driver

I've got Logitech G9x mouse. Gaming mouse. Great mouse. 
Logitech doesn't support it under MacOS X. 
Mouse works perfectly (as far as I can see ) with standard Mac OS driver. (ie right/left/middle buttons and scroll works. What doesn't work are thumb buttons. I've got used to them to go back/forward while browsing, etc.

Couple options I've tried, none helped.

1. Logitech Control Center (LCC v.3.5.1-28) - did not recognize mouse. Expected.
2. [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com) - no support for OS X Lion with repots on kernel crashes from users of OS X Lion. didn't try, as it's not stable solution.
3. [Steer Mouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) didn't recognize G9x on Mac. But did recognize couple other mices I had (ie mx revolution, vx revolution)

Option left: Write own driver. How?

Did I miss anything? Any other drivers out there, I didn't find? (I found a lot of enhancers for magic mouse, or whatever it's called)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Better touch tool](http://blog.boastr.net/). Freeware. You can assign macros to any button with this wonderful tool.

Comment: Thanks. I've started using it shortly after I opened this topic.

Comment: did you managed to assign actions to side buttons in BetterTouchTool for Logitech G9x? When I'm clicking on "Click here to select mouse button" it's not recognizing side buttons (button 7, button 8 I guess). My driver comes from `Logitech Gaming Software 8.96.38` on `macOS Sierra 10.12.6` G9x Laser Mouse: Product ID: 0xc066 Vendor ID: 0x046d (Logitech Inc.) Version: 58.02 Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec Manufacturer: Logitech Location ID: 0x02143000 / 8 Current Available (mA): 500 Current Required (mA): 98 Extra Operating Current (mA): 0